# Where is the postfix log on Sierra?

Tags: email, macos, logs

I am running OS X 10.12.3. I do not have the OS X Server package installed, but I know postfix comes as part of the standard (non-server) installation.

I have the occasional need to send emails from the command line and although I can send emails just fine using the 'mail' command, I cannot for the life of me find any kind of log that shows the progress and/or status of a sent mail item.

Despite what this answer says ([mail and mailx fail to send emails to gmail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89663/mail-and-mailx-fail-to-send-emails-to-gmail/89665#89665)), `/var/log/mail.log` does **not** exist, at least not on Sierra. I have scoured the config files in `/etc/postfix` trying to find a reference to a log directory but didn't find one. I've even tried using the `-mtime` option of the `find` command to locate any changed files immediately after sending an email, but to no avail. All that comes up are the temporary storage locations within `/var/spool/postfix`, but none of those files are actually just a plain old log file.

I read this post ([Is there any documentation on the macOS Sierra new logging system?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259415/is-there-any-documentation-on-the-macos-sierra-new-logging-system)) about the new logging approach on Sierra, but it didn't solve my problem. I've checked `system.log` and although there are a few messages containing `postfix`, they are only about the service exiting, not about mail items being sent.

Does postfix even write a log entry on Sierra when you send an email?

Any info on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This works for me:

```
log stream --predicate  '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp")' --info
```

---

#### Explanation:

`--predicate` is used to filter the log. In this case it looks for the process `"smtpd"` or `"smtp"`

`--info` shows all messages down to info level, which is good for most purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It just outputs `Filtering the log data using "process == "smtpd" OR process == "smtp""`.

Comment: @HappyFace, this command starts filtering, so after that you get log messages when you start accessing smtp.

Comment: Needs sudo for me.

Comment: so, doesn't exists a plain log file?

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Do you know where the file is on the FS, though (I don't XD)?